# Javascript score counter keeps adding no matter the result

Tags: javascript

massive noob here.

I'm making a rock paper scissor game in which one of the functions called 'game',
counts the score between the player and the computer over 5 rounds.

The problem I am having is that no matter whether the player wins loses or draws, +1 is added to the score every time, instead of -1 for a loss and maintaining the score on a draw.

```js
function game() {
  var roundCount = 0;
  var score = 0;

  while (roundCount < 5) {
    playRound(prompt("Rock, Paper or Scissors?"), computerPlay());

    if (resultMessage == "You Win. Rock beats Scissors" || "You Win. Paper beats Rock" || "You Win. Scissor beats Paper") {
      score++;
    } else if (resultMessage == "Draw") {
      score = score;
    } else {
      score--;
    }
    console.log(score)
    roundCount = roundCount + 1;
  }
  return score;
}

console.log(game());
```

Comment: Give yourself some credit, noobs don't make rock paper scissors :)

Comment: I'm disappointed this isn't paper/rock/scissors/lizard/spock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will always return true:

`resultMessage == "You Win. Rock beats Scissors" || "You Win. Paper beats Rock" || "You Win. Scissor beats Paper"`

Because the second and third dysjuncts are strings, which are always true.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This does not work:

```
if(resultMessage == "You Win. Rock beats Scissors" || "You Win. Paper beats Rock" || "You Win. Scissor beats Paper") {
    score++;

}
```

You have to compare each value:

```
if(resultMessage === "You Win. Rock beats Scissors" || resultMessage === "You Win. Paper beats Rock" || resultMessage === "You Win. Scissor beats Paper") {
    score++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the `playRound()` function by returning a value of `-1,0,1` (-1=>lose, 0=>draw, 1=>win). You can then directly add this to the score and it will save you comparing string values. I've included a code sample that demonstrates this, but you would need to replace the `playRound(choice)` function with your own logic to generate a computer choice, test for win/draw/lose, and return the correct response. Goodluck :)

```
function playRound(choice) {
  //replace this random win/draw/lose function with play logic
  let randomResult = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) - 1);
  return randomResult;
}

function game() {
  //init round and score variables
  let roundCount = 0;
  let score = 0;

  //play 5 rounds
  while (roundCount < 5) {
    //get users choice
    let userChoice = prompt("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?");

    //play round and get result (-1 => loss, 0 => draw, 1=> win)
    score += playRound(userChoice);

    //print current score and increment round count
    console.log("Current Score: " + score);
    roundCount++;
  }

  //print final result (no need to check for draw as we have an odd number of rounds)
  console.log("Final Score: " + score);
  if (score < 0) {
    console.log("You lost the game :(");
  } else {
    console.log("You won the game :)");
  }
}

//start game
game();
```